# VerifyUser or VerifyPhoneNumber ? Which makes more sense, better and standard? And Why?

Tags: naming-conventions, standards, registration, sms-verification

In a mobile app, users register themselves based on their phone numbers (like WhatsApp, Uber, Careem etc). User enters his phone Number, app sends him verification code, then user sends back that verification code, app verifies if the verification code sent by user is correct.
My question is that what should we call the part of the process where the app verifies the verification code? Verification Of User Or Verification Of Phone Number? Which makes more sense? And Why? Which is standard?

Answer (score 0):

It verify both user and mobile no. Mobile no is used as identity of the user. So it is helpful in the future when user forget his password . So we can say it verify mobile which is further linked to the user.